# Websphere Server Profile for different node and cell name

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-8

I'm relatively new to Websphere. I have created a WAS ( Websphere Application Server 8.5) profile *configuration* on local, manually from scratch which contains multiple data sources, queues, connection factories and activation specifications. ( Windows 7 PC). I backed this up using backupConfig.bat. I wish to replicate this profile configuration on another system where the Websphere Application Server (installation cannot be altered) has a **different Node and Cell** name. Is there a way where I can replicate it , without having to manually create the resources again,one-by-one , in the local WAS profile on the new system? When I googled this, it threw up the manageprofiles command, though I am not sure if it's backup option will work in my case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If these are simple queues, datasource etc you can use Property based configuration - see [Using properties files to manage system configuration](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_property_configuration.html).
You export configuration from one cell and import to the other.

If you have few elements you can use [WebSphere Configuration Migration Tool](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Configuration_Migration_Tool) (Eclipse plugin), which will allow you to select graphically which resources to move - it generates jython script that you can execute on target environment.